# Prevent variable div size from moving centered image

Tags: css, html

In the code below I have 3 divs, where the 1st and 3rd divs are tables that are filled text of varying lengths (decided by the user) on a user submit.  The 2nd div is an image.  When a user submits and text is filled into the tables the center image (2nd div) moves depending on the text.  For example, if the longest word of either tables is on the left table, the image will shift to the right, along with the right table.  If the longest word in each table are the same length, nothing will move.

How can I ensure that the 2nd div stays centered no matter the length of text in the divs on either side of it?

```
   <div class="text_tables" id="left_table">
            <table>
                <tr><td><span class = "output render" id = "text1"></span></td></tr>
                <tr><td><span class = "output render" id = "text2"></span></td></tr>
                <tr><td><span class = "output render" id = "text3"></span></td></tr>
                <tr><td><span class = "output render" id = "text4"></span></td></tr>
            </table>  
        </div>  
        <div class="text_tables">
            <img id="doge1" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/doge1.png') }}">
            <img id="doge2" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/doge2.jpg') }}">
            <img id="doge3" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/doge3.jpg') }}">
        </div>
        <div class="text_tables" id="right_table">
            <table>
                <tr><td><span class = "output render" id = "text6"></span></td></tr>
                <tr><td><span class = "output render" id = "text7"></span></td></tr>
                <tr><td><span class = "output render" id = "text8"></span></td></tr>
                <tr><td><span class = "output render" id = "text9"></span></td></tr>     
            </table> 
        </div>
```

Here is all of the CSS that affects the above:

```
.text_tables {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

#left_table{
  margin-right: 50px;
}

#right_table{
  margin-left: 50px;
}
div.jumbo {
  padding: 10px 0 30px 0;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}
```

Comment: You should include some CSS on what you've tried so far so we have a bit more to go on.

Comment: CSS has been added above.

Answer (score 1):

So tell me is this fine? :) http://jsfiddle.net/UqRAc/

You must put all that in one div, after that giv that div some class and add display:table; on that class. All div's you want that be center in middle you must add display:table-cell; and vertical-align:middle;

```
.tables {
    display: table;
}
#left_table {
    width:30%;
    display: table-cell;
}
#image-set {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#right_table {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 30%;
}
```

And that is it :)

Comment: Thanks for this, but it is not working properly.  The image is not staying centered and the tables are not on either side of the image

Comment: @Barnaby You can add `text-align: center;` to `#image-set` on josephyn's code above and it will keep the images centered for you. As for the tables not being on each side, I'm looking at the fiddle now and they are on each side respectively with the images div at the dead center. Is is possible some other CSS may be clashing on your side?

Comment: @Barnaby code from jsfiddle is not sutable for you maybe, but you must do that for yourself. I show you concept how you can vertical-align, and adamj show how to center image in that div. I cant do more because you didit give me more information. I dont know your layout etc :)

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I will trying working with both of your answers.